# Linux - grep is not working as expected in CircleCI

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

My laptop is Mac and CircleCI uses Linux and I have to run shell script in CircleCI like below.

```bsh
SOME_ERROR_TEXT="some error text verbose verbose"

if yarn schema-codegen | grep "$SOME_ERROR_TEXT"; then
  echo "success!"
  exit 1
else
  echo "failure!"
fi
```

The result of `yarn schmea-codegen` contains `SOME_EROR_TEXT`.

```
some error text verbose verbose lorem ipsum dfaskldjfskdljfldsakjfkldsjflksdjf
dsflsdjflkjdsfjlkdsjfljdslkfjlkdsjfjdsljfldsjfkjjj
     11123123213123
 '''''
```

This script is working on my Mac, but it is not working on CircleCI environment. Is there wrong syntax in my script? If not, I will solve this problem on CI. Thanks

Comment: Error messages often go to stderr not stdout - are you sure that's not the case here?

Comment: @steeldriver Oh, you were right! I solved it by stderr. Thanks!